# Exit Python script run from Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I know that the way to terminate a Python script is with `raise SystemExit` or with `sys.exit()` which is the same eventually.

However when I run it in Eclipse-Pydev (Ctrl+F11) and I exit from it, the program seems to be exiting, all windows are disappearing, put the Python process is still there in the task manager. The *Terminate* and *Terminate All* buttons remain active in Eclipse too. Pressing one of those kills it properly.

My script is terminating just fine if it has been run from the windows command prompt.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: are you making threads (or proccesses?) that may be left around? or are you using windows and leaving top level windows around?

Comment: no threads or processes, I use OpenCV windows only.